# Canvas stuttering/drawing same frame twice, frame rate drops to 30 FPS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, canvas, requestanimationframe

Ive been having a big issue with performance for the game I'm writing. For some reason while playing, the game stutters and seems to either draw the same frame twice or just skip drawing for that frame. As you can see in the image, for some reason when this jank/stutter happens the FPS drops to 30 and the frame time is twice as long. These stutters happen extremely frequently, every 1-5 seconds. Ive tested for memory leaks nothing unusual, tested for garbage collection, nothing unusual. The three functions that are called to move/render the game objects are moveAllGameRectangles(); renderTheGameObjects(); checkForCollisonsRectangles(); (In that order). They are called using requestAnimationFrame in the update() function. This is my first attempt at creating a game so any help would be great.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLPTd.png)

```
(function() {
var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ds = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

var theMaxWidth = c.width / 4.5;

if (c.height === 1743 || c.height === 1744 || c.height === 1740) {
    var gameVelocity = 60;
} else {
    var gameVelocity = 70;
}

var so = Math.round(c.height / gameVelocity + 65);

var halfVelocity = gameVelocity * 4;
var halfVelocityModulus = gameVelocity * 2;

var modulusNumber = 17;

var OPENING = 0
var LOADING = 1
var BUILD_MENU = 2
var BUILD_MAP = 3
var PLAYING = 4
var LOST = 5
var SETTINGS = 6

assetsLoaded = [];
cargoAnimation = [];
gameObjectsArray = [];
menuObjectsArray = [];
movingMenuObjectsArray = [];
assetsToLoad = [];
whatToMove = [];
gameObjectsPlayingArray = [];
movingGameObjectsArray = [];
lossObjectsArray = [];
settingsObjectArray = [];
messages = [];
theMaxArray = [];
messagesHighScore = [];
settingsTextArray = [];
loadTheFontBeforeArray = [];

randomNumber = 0;
randomGameNumber = 0;

var touchAllowed = false;
var collisionOrNot = false;
var gameRunning = true;
var loaded = false;
var settingsItem1Checked = false;

var practiceModeOn = false;
var interval = null;
var gameInterval = null;

assetsLoaded = 0;
doneLoading = false;

var gameState = OPENING;

var cargo = new Image();
cargo.src = "../www/img/cargo.png";
cargoAnimation.push(cargo);

var menuObjects = new Image();
menuObjects.src = "../www/img/loadingScreenSpriteSheet.png";
assetsToLoad.push(menuObjects);

var gameObjects = new Image();
gameObjects.src = "../www/img/gamePlayingSprites.png";
assetsToLoad.push(gameObjects);


function loadHandler() {
    assetsLoaded++;
    if (assetsLoaded === assetsToLoad.length) {
        touchAllowed = true;
        gameState = BUILD_MENU;
    }
}



window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", touchUpHandler, false);
});
c.addEventListener("touchstart", touchdownhandler, false);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    gameState = LOADING;
});

// backgroundSquare menu
var bSquare = Object.create(mainObject);
bSquare.sourceX = 0;
bSquare.sourceY = 0;
bSquare.sourceWidth = 256;
bSquare.sourceHeight = 264;
bSquare.width = c.width / 2 + c.width / 10;
bSquare.height = c.height / 3;
bSquare.x = c.width / 5;
bSquare.y = c.height / 2 - c.height / 6;
menuObjectsArray.push(bSquare);
lossObjectsArray.push(bSquare);

// loss menu
var lSquare = Object.create(mainObject);
lSquare.sourceX = 0;
lSquare.sourceY = 360;
lSquare.sourceWidth = 228;
lSquare.sourceHeight = 92;
lSquare.width = c.width / 2 - c.width / 35;
lSquare.height = c.height / 9;
lSquare.x = c.width / 3 - c.width / 14;
lSquare.y = c.height / 3 + c.height / 25;
lossObjectsArray.push(lSquare);

// play button
var play = Object.create(mainObject);
play.sourceX = 256;
play.sourceY = 0;
play.sourceWidth = 66;
play.sourceHeight = 64;
play.width = c.width / 5;
play.height = c.height / 9;
play.x = c.width / 3 - c.width / 14;
play.y = c.height / 2 + c.height / 100;
menuObjectsArray.push(play);
lossObjectsArray.push(play);

// settingsButton
var settings = Object.create(mainObject);
settings.sourceX = 322;
settings.sourceY = 0;
settings.sourceWidth = 66;
settings.sourceHeight = 64;
settings.width = c.width / 5;
settings.height = c.height / 9;
settings.x = c.width / 3 + c.width / 5 + c.width / 150;
settings.y = c.height / 2 + c.height / 100;
menuObjectsArray.push(settings);
lossObjectsArray.push(settings);

// logo
var logo = Object.create(mainObject);
logo.sourceX = 0;
logo.sourceY = 265;
logo.sourceWidth = 228;
logo.sourceHeight = 92;
logo.width = c.width / 2 - c.width / 35;
logo.height = c.height / 9;
logo.x = c.width / 3 - c.width / 14;
logo.y = c.height / 3 + c.height / 25;
menuObjectsArray.push(logo);


// firstButton
var button1 = Object.create(mainObject);
button1.sourceX = 0;
button1.sourceY = 257;
button1.sourceWidth = 103;
button1.sourceHeight = 120;
button1.width = c.width / 4;
button1.height = c.height / 4;
button1.x = 0;
button1.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button1);

// secondButton
var button2 = Object.create(mainObject);
button2.sourceX = 103;
button2.sourceY = 257;
button2.sourceWidth = 103;
button2.sourceHeight = 120;
button2.width = c.width / 4;
button2.height = c.height / 4;
button2.x = c.width / 4;
button2.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button2);

// thirdButton
var button3 = Object.create(mainObject);
button3.sourceX = 207;
button3.sourceY = 257;
button3.sourceWidth = 103;
button3.sourceHeight = 120;
button3.width = c.width / 4;
button3.height = c.height / 4;
button3.x = c.width / 4 + c.width / 4;
button3.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button3);

// fourButton
var button4 = Object.create(mainObject);
button4.sourceX = 309;
button4.sourceY = 257;
button4.sourceWidth = 103;
button4.sourceHeight = 120;
button4.width = c.width / 4;
button4.height = c.height / 4;
button4.x = c.width / 4 + c.width / 4 + c.width / 4;
button4.y = c.height - c.height / 6;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(button4);

// theGameCharacter
var theGameCharacter = Object.create(mainObject);
theGameCharacter.sourceX = 0;
theGameCharacter.sourceY = 380;
theGameCharacter.sourceWidth = 60;
theGameCharacter.sourceHeight = 60;
theGameCharacter.width = c.width / 6;
theGameCharacter.height = c.height / 11;
theGameCharacter.x = c.width / 24;
theGameCharacter.y = c.height * .75 - c.height / 15;
gameObjectsPlayingArray.push(theGameCharacter);


var settingsMenu = Object.create(mainObject);
settingsMenu.sourceX = 256;
settingsMenu.sourceY = 64;
settingsMenu.sourceWidth = 66;
settingsMenu.sourceHeight = 64;
settingsMenu.width = c.width / 6;
settingsMenu.height = c.height / 11;
settingsMenu.x = c.width / 20;
settingsMenu.y = c.height / 35;
settingsObjectArray.push(settingsMenu);

var settingsMenuNonChecked = Object.create(mainObject);
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceX = 256;
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceY = 180;
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceWidth = 182;
settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceHeight = 50;
settingsMenuNonChecked.width = c.width / 2;
settingsMenuNonChecked.height = c.height / 13;
settingsMenuNonChecked.x = c.width / 10;
settingsMenuNonChecked.y = c.height / 5;
settingsObjectArray.push(settingsMenuNonChecked);

timerMessage = Object.create(messageObject);
timerMessage.x = c.width / 2;
timerMessage.y = c.height / 10;
timerMessage.font = getFont();
timerMessage.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
timerMessage.visible = true;
messages.push(timerMessage);

timerMessageHighScore = Object.create(messageObject);
timerMessageHighScore.x = c.width / 2;
timerMessageHighScore.y = c.height / 5;
timerMessageHighScore.font = getFont();
timerMessageHighScore.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
timerMessageHighScore.visible = true;
messagesHighScore.push(timerMessageHighScore);

settingsText = Object.create(messageObject);
settingsText.x = c.width / 1.6;
settingsText.y = c.height / 4.7;
settingsText.font = getSmallerFont();
settingsText.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
settingsText.visible = true;
settingsText.text = "Practice Mode"
settingsTextArray.push(settingsText);

loadTheFontBefore = Object.create(messageObject);
loadTheFontBefore.font = getSmallerFont();
loadTheFontBefore.fillStyle = "#3000ff";
loadTheFontBefore.x = -c.width;
loadTheFontBefore.y = -c.height;
loadTheFontBefore.visible = false;
loadTheFontBeforeArray.push(loadTheFontBefore);


function getFont() {
    var size = c.width / 20 * 2
    return (size | 0) + 'px neuropolitical rg';
}

function getSmallerFont() {
    var size = c.width / 30 * 2
    return (size | 0) + 'px neuropolitical rg';
}


update();

function update() {

    ds.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);


    //console.log(cargoAnimation.length, gameObjectsArray.length, menuObjectsArray.length, movingMenuObjectsArray.length, assetsToLoad.length, whatToMove.length, gameObjectsPlayingArray.length, movingGameObjectsArray.length, lossObjectsArray.length, settingsObjectArray.length, messages.length)

    req = requestAnimationFrame(update, c);

    switch (gameState) {

        case LOADING:
            loadHandler();
            break;

        case BUILD_MENU:
            moveAllRectangles();
            renderMenuObjects();
            beforeLoadTheFont();
            break;

        case BUILD_MAP:
            moveAllGameRectangles();
            renderTheGameObjects();
            checkForCollisonsRectangles();

            break;

        case PLAYING:
            break;

        case SETTINGS:
            renderSettingsObjects();
            renderSettingText();
            break;
    }
}


function checkForCollisonsRectangles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < movingGameObjectsArray.length; i++) {

        var collisionOrNot = hitTestRectangle(theGameCharacter, movingGameObjectsArray[i]);

        if (collisionOrNot && movingGameObjectsArray[0].y > theGameCharacter.y + theGameCharacter.height - c.height / 80) {
            collisionOrNot === false;
            return;
        }

        if (collisionOrNot) {
            stoptimer();
            resettimer();
            touchAllowed = true;
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(req);
            displayRestartMenu();
            gameRunning = false;
            logHighScore();
            showHighScore();
            return;
        }
    }
}

function logHighScore() {
    console.log(practiceModeOn)
    if(practiceModeOn === false){
    theMaxArray.push(timerMessage.text);
    Array.max = function(theMaxArray) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, theMaxArray);
    };
    var maximum = Array.max(theMaxArray);
    timerMessageHighScore.text = maximum
}
}

function showHighScore() {
    console.log(practiceModeOn)
if(practiceModeOn === false){
    if (messagesHighScore.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messagesHighScore.length; i++) {
            var message = messagesHighScore[i];
            if (message.visible) {
                ds.font = message.font;
                ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
                ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
                ds.textAlign = 'center';
                ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function renderSettingText() {
    if (settingsTextArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < settingsTextArray.length; i++) {
            var message = settingsTextArray[i];
            if (message.visible) {
                ds.font = message.font;
                ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
                ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
                ds.textAlign = 'center';
                ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
            }
        }
    }
}

function beforeLoadTheFont() {
    if (loaded === true) {
        return;
    }
    if (loadTheFontBeforeArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < loadTheFontBeforeArray.length; i++) {
            var message = loadTheFontBeforeArray[i];
            ds.font = message.font;
            ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
            ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
            ds.textAlign = 'center';
            ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
        }
    }
    loaded = true;
    console.log("runn")
}

function displayRestartMenu() {
    if (lossObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lossObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = lossObjectsArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}

function touchUpHandler() {

    touchX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - c.offsetLeft;
    touchY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - c.offsetTop;

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, play)) {


        if (gameState === BUILD_MENU) {
            movingMenuObjectsArray = [];
            startstoptimer();
            gameState = BUILD_MAP;
            gameRunning = true;
            touchAllowed = false;
        } else {
            if (touchAllowed === true) {
                movingMenuObjectsArray = [];
                startstoptimer();
                movingGameObjectsArray = [];
                update();
                gameState = BUILD_MAP;
                gameRunning = true;
                touchAllowed = false;
            }


        }
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settings)) {
        if (touchAllowed === true) {
            gameState = SETTINGS;
            if (!gameRunning) {
                update();
                movingGameObjectsArray = [];
            }
            gameRunning = true;
        }
    }


    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settings)) {
        if (touchAllowed === true) {
            gameState = SETTINGS;
            if (!gameRunning) {
                update();
                movingGameObjectsArray = [];
            }
            gameRunning = true;
        }
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settingsMenu)) {
        if (gameState === SETTINGS) {
            gameState = BUILD_MENU;
        }
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, settingsMenuNonChecked)) {
        console.log(settingsItem1Checked)
        if(settingsItem1Checked === true){
            console.log("doing")
            if (c.height === 1743 || c.height === 1744 || c.height === 1740) {
             gameVelocity = 60;
            } else {
             gameVelocity = 70;
            }
             modulusNumber = 17;
             settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceY = 180;
             settingsItem1Checked = false;
             practiceModeOn = false;
             return;
        }
        if(settingsItem1Checked === false){
            console.log("doing")
            if (c.height === 1743 || c.height === 1744 || c.height === 1740) {
             gameVelocity = 120;
            } else {
             gameVelocity = 140;
            }
             modulusNumber = 30;
             settingsMenuNonChecked.sourceY = 128;
             settingsItem1Checked = true;
             practiceModeOn = true;
             return;
        }

    }



}



function touchdownhandler() {

    touchX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - c.offsetLeft;
    touchY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - c.offsetTop;

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button1)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width / 23;

    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button2)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width * .25 + c.width / 23;

    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button3)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width * .5 + c.width / 23;

    }

    if (hitTestPoint(touchX, touchY, button4)) {

        theGameCharacter.x = c.width * .75 + c.width / 23;

    }

}

function renderTheGameObjects() {

    if (movingGameObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < movingGameObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = movingGameObjectsArray[i];
            sprite.y += sprite.vy;
            ds.drawImage(
                gameObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
            if (sprite.y > c.height - c.height / 6) {
                var removeThis = sprite;
            }
        }
    }

    removeTheMenuObject(removeThis, movingGameObjectsArray);

    if (messages.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            var message = messages[i];
            if (message.visible) {
                ds.font = message.font;
                ds.fillStyle = message.fillStyle;
                ds.textBaseline = message.textBaseline;
                ds.textAlign = 'center';
                ds.fillText(message.text, message.x, message.y);
            }
        }
    }
    if (gameObjectsPlayingArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gameObjectsPlayingArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = gameObjectsPlayingArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                gameObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}


function hitTestPoint(pointX, pointY, sprite) {
    return pointX > sprite.left() && pointX < sprite.right() && pointY > sprite.top() && pointY < sprite.bottom();
}

function renderMenuObjects() {
    if (menuObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < menuObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = menuObjectsArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}

function renderSettingsObjects() {
    if (settingsObjectArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < settingsObjectArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = settingsObjectArray[i];
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
        }
    }
}

function moveAllGameRectangles() {
    gameInterval = gameInterval + 1;
    if (gameInterval % modulusNumber === 0 || gameInterval === 1) {
        var randomGameNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (randomGameNumber === 1) {

            //the green game object
            var leftSideSpriteGame1 = Object.create(mainObject);
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceX = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceY = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceWidth = 310;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.sourceHeight = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.width = c.width * .75;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.height = c.height / 14;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.x = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.y = -65;
            leftSideSpriteGame1.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(leftSideSpriteGame1);

        }

        if (randomGameNumber === 2) {

            //the red game object
            var leftSideSpriteGame2 = Object.create(mainObject);
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceX = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceY = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceWidth = 207;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.sourceHeight = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.width = c.width * .5;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.height = c.height / 14;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.x = 0
            leftSideSpriteGame2.y = -65;
            leftSideSpriteGame2.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(leftSideSpriteGame2);

            var rightSideSpriteGame2 = Object.create(mainObject);
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceX = 310;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceY = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceWidth = 103;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.sourceHeight = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.width = c.width * .25;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.height = c.height / 14;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.x = c.width * .75;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.y = -65;
            rightSideSpriteGame2.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(rightSideSpriteGame2);
        }

        if (randomGameNumber === 3) {
            //the blue game object
            var leftSideSpriteGame3 = Object.create(mainObject);
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceX = 0;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceY = 128;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceWidth = 103;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.sourceHeight = 64;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.width = c.width * .25;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.height = c.height / 14;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.x = 0
            leftSideSpriteGame3.y = -65;
            leftSideSpriteGame3.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(leftSideSpriteGame3);

            var rightSideSpriteGame3 = Object.create(mainObject);
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceX = 207;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceY = 128;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceWidth = 207;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.sourceHeight = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.width = c.width * .5;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.height = c.height / 14;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.x = c.width * .5;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.y = -65;
            rightSideSpriteGame3.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(rightSideSpriteGame3);
        }
        if (randomGameNumber === 4) {
            //the pink game object
            var rightSideSpriteGame4 = Object.create(mainObject);
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceX = 104;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceY = 192;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceWidth = 310;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.sourceHeight = 64;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.width = c.width * .75;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.height = c.height / 14;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.x = c.width * .25;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.y = -65;
            rightSideSpriteGame4.vy = c.height / gameVelocity;
            movingGameObjectsArray.push(rightSideSpriteGame4);
        }
    }
}



function moveAllRectangles() {
    interval = interval + 1;
    if (interval % 60 === 0 || interval === 1) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        if (randomNumber === 1) {

            var seg1 = Object.create(segment1);
            seg1.width = c.width * .75;
            seg1.height = c.height / 14;
            seg1.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg1.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg1);

        }
        if (randomNumber === 2) {

            var seg2 = Object.create(segment2);
            seg2.width = c.width * .5;
            seg2.height = c.height / 14;
            seg2.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg2.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg2);

            var segL = Object.create(segment3);
            segL.width = c.width * .25;
            segL.height = c.height / 14;
            segL.x = c.width * .75;
            segL.y = -c.height / 14;
            segL.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(segL);

        }
        if (randomNumber === 3) {

            var seg3 = Object.create(segment4);
            seg3.width = c.width * .25;
            seg3.height = c.height / 14;
            seg3.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg3.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg3);

            var seg3R = Object.create(segment5);
            seg3R.width = c.width * .5;
            seg3R.height = c.height / 14;
            seg3R.x = c.width * .5;
            seg3R.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg3R.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg3R);

        }
        if (randomNumber === 4) {

            var seg4 = Object.create(segment6);
            seg4.width = c.width * .75;
            seg4.height = c.height / 14;
            seg4.x = c.width * .25;
            seg4.y = -c.height / 14;
            seg4.vy = c.height / halfVelocity;
            movingMenuObjectsArray.push(seg4);
        }
    }

    if (movingMenuObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < movingMenuObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            var sprite = movingMenuObjectsArray[i];
            sprite.y += sprite.vy;
            ds.drawImage(
                menuObjects,
                sprite.sourceX, sprite.sourceY,
                sprite.sourceWidth, sprite.sourceHeight,
                sprite.x, sprite.y,
                sprite.width, sprite.height
            );
            if (sprite.y > c.height) {
                var removeThis = sprite;
            }
        }
    }
    removeTheMenuObject(removeThis, movingMenuObjectsArray);

}

function removeTheMenuObject(objectToRemove, array) {
    var i = array.indexOf(objectToRemove);
    if (i !== -1) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

function renderGameObjects() {
    if (gameObjectsArray.length !== 0) {
        ds.drawImage(
            image,
            0, 0,
            414, 736,
            0, 0,
            414, 736
        );

    }
}
}());
```

Comment: Just a quick check, are you only checking for collisions on blocks that you can see? also I have just copied your code into jsFiddle and mainObject is undefined :(

Comment: I am checking for collisions on all blocks but I am removing them once they go past the screen at the bottom. So I am only checking for 4 blocks at a time max. I am not sure why it isnt working on jsfiddle

Comment: Is there any chance you could create a simple jsFiddle because I couldn't :(.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/zcs2Lkoa/ I am using touch handlers that will not allow you to play the game for some reason, I am not sure how to convert those to work on jsfiddle. Disable the checkForCollisonsRectangles(); function when game is playing so you don't have to worry about actually playing. Other than that you should be able to see the jank and stuttering even when the game loads in the "lobby". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here is an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/zcs2Lkoa/1/) that will work on desktop too, but I won't go through the 1400+ lines of code to see what is "stuttering", and I can't make a better score than 5 blocks so I can't even reproduce this issue...

Comment: Here is a [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/zcs2Lkoa/6/) that works without collision detection making it easy to reproduce the issue.  Just right click the output, go to timeline and you will see FPS drops to 30 randomly. Most of the code is from external files that I added and is not important with the issue. I added a line at line 579 to show where the important code starts. The two functions that are causing the issue are the moveAllGameRectangles(); renderTheGameObjects(); which are on lines, 1219 and 1137. I don't think the issue is outside of the functions.